# Network Load Balancing Server

Tags: load-balancing

I want to create NLB (Network Load Balance) server, do I require any specific software or hardware for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of different hardware solutions to network load balancing ( F5, Foundry, Cisco etc. ) as well as software based solutions and it's even included in the Linux Kernel ( LVS ).

Without knowing a little more about what you are trying to load balance, what traffic levels and what reliability you require it's difficult to make recommendations.